# PDF Package in Laravel is not writing Arabic letters

Tags: laravel, pdf, barryvdh

I am using this function to print payslip as PDF, it's working for English content but the client has his data in Arabic so instead of Arabic letters it displays "?????".

I tried many fonts that supports Arabic but it's still not working.

This is the controller function:

```
public function printPdf(Payslip $payslip)
{
  $month_year = $payslip->month_year;
  $employee = Employee::get();
 
  PDF::setOptions([
     'dpi' => 150,
     'defaultFont' => 'arial', // A font that supports Arabic
     'tempDir' => storage_path('temp')
  ]);
    
  $pdf = PDF::loadview('backend.salary.payslip.pdf', $payslip->toArray(), $employee);
  return $pdf->stream();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding UTF support in your php file?

Comment: im using this in my blade file <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Answer (score 0):

Which package are you using?

We have a feature to printing pdf files in different languages too. We use [mpdf/mpdf](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf), works like a charm.

Comment: im using Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf

Comment: I recall that one doesn't work well with multi languages, try the one above.

Comment: im installing it rn and will try it. thank u